# Transferring Hard Drive to New Laptop - No Bootable Device

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bootable-media

My old laptop is unable to charge now, so I got a new laptop. I want to put the old hard drive, which was running Windows 7, into my new laptop which is sold with Windows 8. I tried just inserting the drive into the new laptop, but it was unable to find a bootable device in the old hard drive, which I'm guessing is because of driver incompatibility. It spit back the error:

```
EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (20-89-84-F7-51-39) boot failed.
```

Is there any way for me to replace my hard drive?
It would help to note that I can't go on the old hard drive because of the charging problem I mentioned with the old laptop, so I can only work on the new laptop.

Comment: you better copy your important data in new laptop and sell your old harddisk

Comment: I would just get an external case for that old hard drive and plug it in to USB and get what data you need from it.  Hard drives die someday too.  Use the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a fresh Windows 7 install on the new laptop, inclusing all programs you use. You can use the serial number from the old install.

If you worry about your data - you can copy the user folder to the new installation. That will work. Make sure you copy all data, including hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your laptop is trying to boot into the wrong device.

Verify that your laptop can see your old hard drive. If it does, then make sure that the boot order is such that it is the first device to be booted from (at the moment it appears to be trying to boot from the network).

You can purchase HDD "docking stations" online to get your data back. Here's an example: http://www.amazon.co.uk/TeckNet-Docking-Including-External-Comaptible/dp/B00IS7Y96I